# Bootstrap responsive menu 2,000 lines of CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This question has been totally rewritten.

I'm handcoding a site. I'm a newbie. I need to create a very basic horizontal nav bar and then at smaller sizes have a hamburger icon (or word 'menu') to reveal the nav links.

To save reinventing the wheel I've gone to the Bootstrap website and using the customize options downloaded just the 'navs' 'navbar' components and Javascript and JQuery plugins that look relevant.

The download doesn't include any HTML. I presume I have to get the HTML from the seperate 'Components' page? Or do I have to write the HTML by hand, making sure I use the classes specified in the CSS?

I was hoping the CSS would be around 20 lines of code. To my surprise there are two stylesheets (bootstrap-theme.css and bootstrap.css). The first has 597 lines of code. The second 1,766 lines of code.

For something so simple, why is there over 2,000 lines of code? I need to remove 99% of the CSS which is going to be a big pain. Which bits can I remove?

The download also includes something called config.json What is this? I was hoping for a bit of JavaScript to make the nav appear when the hamburger icon is clicked.

Is Bootstrap the right place to look for small bits of functionality? Where else might provide the CSS and JavaScript to create a responsive menu?

Thank you

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: have you seen this? http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: You'd use the minified versions too. Anyway this quesion is out of scope for SO.

Comment: Where would be the most appropriate place to ask this question? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is a way you can customize the bootstrap code the way you want in an easy way (and get less lines of code..):

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

> I know that you should not answer only with links, but I thought it
>   would be appropriate in this case

Comment: What are "Less files"? I have never used preprocessors so I would rather stick with vanilla CSS.

Comment: @Markeee if you do not see the benefit of using Bootstrap continue to code your own css. Bootstrap's focus on a mobile-first responsive design is, I think, its main benefit. I hate having to re-think my media query breakpoints on a site each time.

Comment: [This](http://lesscss.org/) is LESS.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you.